# Select the distinct date intervals From Table in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

A table with From Date and To Date. The query should remove those rows where FromDate and ToDate is in the interval of already existed row.

Table

```
    bookingID   FromDate                  ToDate
    15         2015-04-29 17:00:00.000    2015-04-29 18:00:00.000
    13         2015-05-01 10:00:00.000    2015-05-01 14:00:00.000
    14         2015-05-01 13:00:00.000    2015-05-01 14:00:00.000
```

Result

```
bookingID   FromDate                  ToDate
13         2015-05-01 10:00:00.000    2015-05-01 14:00:00.000
15         2015-04-29 17:00:00.000    2015-04-29 18:00:00.000
```

As on Date 2015-05-01, Row 1 covers time from 10am to 2pm. Row 2 with time 1pm to 2pm is already covered by Row 1.

**EDIT**

To be more clear with the case, There cannot be more the two intervals in the Table i.e. A in intreval B is the only level of complexity.
SO if A in intreval B when B should be deleted

Comment: This is something that should really be done with a scripting language such as php or python

Comment: @TobyAllen: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking if it is easily possible in SQL

Comment: SQL isnt really a proper programming language the logic here is quite complex, so I would think it needs a simple script or an insanely complicated stored procedure.

Comment: Are you trying to actually delete the rows (you said "remove the rows") or are you trying to do a query which will not select those rows?

Comment: @PeterBowers : as per xQbert question, I want to to simply eliminate bookings which are fully contained in another

Comment: So you are actually trying to delete records from your table?

Comment: @PeterBowers : Yes, the intervals which fall in between should get deleted. I am updating my question for better understanding

Comment: I disagree with @Toby. This is well-suited to SQL and probably the better even than the other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this with an `EXISTS` sub-query...

```
SELECT * FROM table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM table b 
    WHERE b.FromDate <= a.FromDate 
    AND b.ToDate >= a.ToDate 
    AND a.bookingID != b.bookingID )
```

I'm not sure exactly how you are defining "in the interval" but this should give you the right idea.

Since I now understand that you are trying to actually DELETE the records from the table, you would have to reverse the logic and make it a DELETE query instead of a SELECT query:

```
DELETE FROM table a
WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM table b 
    WHERE b.FromDate <= a.FromDate 
    AND b.ToDate >= a.ToDate 
    AND a.bookingID != b.bookingID )
```

To allow the case where there may be 2 records with identical `FromDate` and identical `ToDate` we can leave both records like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM table b 
    WHERE b.FromDate <= a.FromDate 
    AND b.ToDate >= a.ToDate 
    AND a.bookingID != b.bookingID
    AND (b.FromDate != a.FromDate OR b.ToDate != a.ToDate) )
```

Or include just one of the records like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM table b 
    WHERE b.FromDate <= a.FromDate 
    AND b.ToDate >= a.ToDate 
    AND a.bookingID != b.bookingID
    AND (b.FromDate != a.FromDate 
         OR b.ToDate != a.ToDate 
         OR a.bookingID < b.bookingID) )
```

(I've moved it back to the SELECT because you can test it in a non-destructive way. It can easily be switched back to the DELETE query by changing the first 2 words to DELETE and getting rid of the NOT.)

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it was removing those rows also which do not match with any other time interval. sorry for "in the interval", I was not able to guess the currect word to be used but I have tried  to explain the meaning of "in the interval" in result.

Comment: I swapped the a and the b in the inner condition - try it again. The double negative is making my head spin a bit...

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood the question. I thought you just wanted to remove the records from the results of your query (which this will do). Since you actually want to delete records from your table, check out the other answers.

Comment: In the result also, the NOT Exists will eliminate those rows which have unique time interval. for example, in the above table specified in question. If there is a row with entry "2015-04-29 17:00:00.000" "2015-04-29 18:00:00.000". It is removing it from the result.

Comment: Really? I tried here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3efca9/1/0 - and it seemed to be working fine...

Comment: You are right, Its working fine iun fiddle. Let me try it once more

Comment: Browers: up 1, Please check this fiddle. It is the exact result which i am getting ( added a row in your Fiddle )  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae068/1

Comment: If there are two bookings with the exact same dates then both would be deleted. I gather from the requirement that that case is not going to happen but I wanted to note the caveat.

Comment: @shawnt00: I can happen, This is where i am structed. otherwise the above answer is refining it fine

Comment: Yep, identical from & to dates on 2 separate records means each "are contained" in the other and therefore each removes the other. If you don't want that then it's relatively easy to leave them BOTH in but it's hard to leave just one in.

Comment: @PeterBowers : Yes, i can filter it out using distinct afterwards.

Comment: Or I suppose you could specify that `a.bookingID < b.bookingID` for that special case.

Comment: You would need to check for "equality" and then use id values to break the tie.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all records which are contained in another another record.

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM tableName A
LEFT JOIN tableName B
 on A.FromDate<= B.FromDate
and A.ToDate>= B.FromDate
and A.bookingID < B.BookingID
```

to Delete..

```
Delete from TableName where ID not in 
(Select b.ID
    FROM tableName A
    LEFT JOIN tableName B
     on A.FromDate<= B.FromDate
    and A.ToDate>= B.FromDate)
and A.bookingID < B.BookingID
```

However if you also need to somehow indicate and process OVERLAP not just fully contained, that's different.  So a clear understanding of what you're trying to accomplish would help.

Are you

1. Wanting to simply eliminate bookings which are fully contained in another?
2. Flag bookings which overlap?
3. Identify bookings which are contained in others?

What you've given us is the technical issue you're trying to solve, but without context and use case, you'll get exactly what you asked for, which may not be the problem you're trying to solve is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: all such solutions work with one level of complexity, but what will be the result if `A in intreval B, and B in interval C, and C in interval D` will it return only the D record?

Comment: @xQbert : Thanks for the answer , Wanting to simply eliminate bookings which are fully contained in another

Comment: @xQbert : I tried the suggested solution. But no luck :(

Comment: You've specified that `A.bookingID < B.BookingID` when I think you actually mean `<>` or `!=` - there's no guarantee of which ID will be greater or smaller and the only thing you care about is that they are not equal.